# Regex pattern single and multiple instance of same character

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm using regex to sanitise strings, I am looking to remove special characters, allow words & numbers and allow spaces in between the words.

the code below works well but I would also like to accept single instances of the - character but stop n times sequentially e.g. ---- take the following string and expected result:

before: 'grey 1.25-2.50mm \ ---- ' '

after:  grey 1.25-2.50mm

```
string clean = Regex.Replace(test, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z./ \w]+", "").Trim();
```

I removed - from my example as it would accept all instances.

Comment: The `0-9a-zA-Z` are redundant if you add `\w` in the character class.

Comment: Try [`[^./ \w-]+|\B-\B`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e.%2f+%5cw-%5d%2b%7c%5cB-%5cB&i=%27grey+1.25-2.50mm+%5c+----+%27+%27&r=).

Comment: thanks Soner, this works as expected.

Comment: Apologies, My thanks should have gone to stribizhev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex for it:

```
string clean = Regex.Replace(@"grey 1.25-2.50mm \ ----", @"([^\w./\s-]+|-{2,})", "")
```